# firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid) being extremely slow recently

Tags: javascript, firebase, performance, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Starting around October `firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid)` is having an extremely slow response time - often reaching more than 60 secs and even more - and then it returns back to normal.

My first suspicion was it's related to the throughput of the API but it doesn't correlate as it happens almost randomly.

Is anyone else facing this issue? It has been a real problem and can't know if there is something wrong with the service or if it's on our end.

```js
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';
const uid = "uid-goes-here";
const data = await firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid);
```

[image: New relic Performance Graph]